# Crash found after submitting the App to iTunes

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Today I have submitted my app to `iTunes` Connect.

I had tested my app thousand times and also distributed my app for testing among my clients.

After approval from all side I finally submitted it to `iTunes`.

But just after submitting I found a `Crash` at some point in the app.

I am very afraid about it. Will my app get rejected ? Now what should I do?

**Edit**
Apple Aprroves my App. Now it is Live :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Apple app approval process is always a little gamble: you never know for sure what will happen.

If you know your app will crash under some conditions then of course changes are higher that your app might get reject by Apple.

So right now you have two options:

1. Wait about 7 days (so long does it take apple to review your app) and see what happens.
2. Cancel the submit (developer reject), fix the crash and resubmit.

Comment: thanks @tropper for you quick response. Their is christmas leave in apple that's why I submitted in hurry. But the Crash will occur in a complex situation. Will still apple will able to detect it

Comment: Like I said: no one can tell you what will happen. I would say if you re-submit your app right now your app will not make it in time before Christmas. So I would play the odds, wait and hope Apple will not encounter the crash. But your app, so you have to decide. ;-)